# How to select specific programmer from multiple when using flashrom

Tags: spi, eeprom

I have 4 CH341A programmers connected to my laptop. They are all connected to the same USB hub. Reading the content of a SPI EEPROM works fine.
How do I select the programmer (of these 4) to be used for reading/writing in flashrom?

At the moment having 4 programmers fulfils no purpose for me, because flashrom has its own ideas about what programmer to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/flashrom/flashrom/blob/staging/ch341a_spi.c), there is only **one** CH341A programmer possible.

Supporting more than one on a PC will require you to change the source code (look for `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(...)` function call). You want to look at the serial number string before using the device.

Note that this will only work if the USB devices have *unique* serial numbers - you can check this with `lsusb -v` for example. Some el-cheapo devices do not have serial numbers or they just use the same number.

Comment: they seem to lack a serial number. :(